# register method IOS SDK for drupal

Tags: ios, objective-c, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using the Drupal IOS SDK to implement the register method. 
My problem is that the code ask me to create a NSDictionary to be used in this method, but in order for the user to register the user must enter the username and the email, which will         be sent to the server to authenticate later on.So, I have two UITextFields to receive the inputs for both username and Email. How do I add the two textfields to solve this problem. 
Here is the code.

```
#pragma mark userRegister
+ (void)userRegister:(NSDictionary *)user
             success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)) success
             failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)) failure {

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/register", kDiosEndpoint, kDiosBaseUser];

    if ([[DIOSSession sharedSession] signRequests]) {
        [[DIOSSession sharedSession] sendSignedRequestWithPath:path
                                                        method:@"POST"
                                                        params:user
                                                       success:success
                                                       failure:failure];
        NSLog (@"sucess %@", path);
    }
    else {
        [[DIOSSession sharedSession] postPath:path
                                   parameters:user
                                      success:success
                                      failure:failure];
        NSLog (@"failed %@", path);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a view and view controller. You can use Interface Builder and storyboard. You may check the documentation how to make it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html

Comment: I've solved this problem now, it turned out that I just have to change the type of NSDictionary and turn it into the NSMutableDictionary. Then add the two textfields into by using the setobject method for key. 

Thanks anyway though.